# Unity - How to spawn hook and have ability reflect to object?

Tags: unity, c#

In this game, I'm trying to make a rope with a hook that bounces or reflects the same as the aim direction, so this rope with a hook has max length when reflecting something, basically hook has a tail/rope that is a `line renderer` that also connected on `fire point` transform, speaking of reflecting object, for example, this happens when the hook hit the wall, the hook bounce first and then the rope reflects the wall.

**PREVIEW**

[image]

when aim with direction

[image]

this is my goal something like this, shoot a hook with a rope that reflects and has the same direction with aim direction

**The script**

- RaycastReflect

```cs
  public Vector3[] positions;
  public Vector3[] pos;
  public int index = 0;

     // Throwing hook or spawn hoo
     public void ThrowHook()
     {
        go = Instantiate(prefabHook, transform.position, transform.rotation);
     }
 
     public void GetRotationObject()
     {
        Vector3 moveVector = (Vector3.up * Player3.instance.newInput_Movement.y - Vector3.left * Player3.instance.newInput_Movement.x);

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") != 0 || Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") != 0)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, moveVector);
        }
     }

     public void ShowRenderer()
     {
        ray = new Ray2D(transform.position, transform.up);

        lineRenderer.positionCount = 1;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        float remainingLength = maxLength;

        for (int i = 0; i < reflections; i++)
        {
            hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, remainingLength, layerMask);

            if (hit)
            {
                lineRenderer.positionCount += 1;
                lineRenderer.SetPosition(lineRenderer.positionCount - 1, hit.point);
                remainingLength -= Vector2.Distance(ray.origin, hit.point);
                Vector2 updatedDirection = Vector2.Reflect(ray.direction, hit.normal);
                ray = new Ray2D(hit.point + updatedDirection * 0.01f, updatedDirection);
                if (hit.collider.tag != "Reflect")
                    break;
            }
            else
            {
                lineRenderer.positionCount += 1;
                lineRenderer.SetPosition(lineRenderer.positionCount - 1, ray.origin + ray.direction * remainingLength);
            }
        }
     }

// To get Line Points
Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I am already able to spawn hook by adding a script that follows line setpoints

- HookBullet

```cs
public RaycastReflection rayCastAim;
   public int speed;
   bool isMove;

   private void OnEnable()
   {
       rayCastAim = FindObjectOfType<RaycastReflection>();

       rayCastAim.index = 0;
       isMove = true;
   }

   private void Update()
   {
       Move();
   }

   public void Move()
   {
       if (isMove)
       {
           transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, rayCastAim.pos[rayCastAim.index], speed * Time.deltaTime);

           // try to keep object facing on the direction
           transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rayCastAim.pos[rayCastAim.index]);

           if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, rayCastAim.pos[rayCastAim.index]) < .5f)
           {
               rayCastAim.index++;
           }

           if (rayCastAim.index >= rayCastAim.pos.Length)
           {
               isMove = false;

               Player3.instance.anim.SetBool("isHoldAttack", Player3.instance.isHoldAttack);

               Player3.instance.isMoving = true;

               Destroy(gameObject);
           }
       }
   }

   private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
   {
       if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemies")
       {
           Debug.Log(collision.gameObject.name);
       }
   }
```

another issue is I don't have any idea to connect the rope `line renderer` to the spawn hook, and how to keep the hook facing exactly the direction I already added `Quaternion.Euler but it's not what I want.

Comment: It's unclear to me what specific problem you're having with this code or the approaches you describe in the text below it.

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry, ill try to describe my problem, so basically, I have a `raycast` with a line renderer that reflects like number picture one, then I want to spawn the prefab hook and the hook moving along the line and the result what I want is like picture number two

like after aiming I want to shoot a bullet in the same direction as aiming and bullet moves in that direction

Comment: I understand what you want to do. What I don't understand is where you're having difficulty doing it.

Comment: I having difficulty with how to make this prefab move like the line 

I already tried to instantiate inside `if(hit)` and move the `prefab by hit.transform.position` multiple by speed

Comment: Multiplying a position by a speed never makes geometric sense. Did you mean to use a direction vector there instead?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a vector move toward to move object follow the line setpoints that I save on the vector array, I already update the script